# Fortify and third-party libraries

Tags: fortify

I am trying to understand in the new version of Fortify SCA [17.10](https://wiki.mobilehealth.va.gov/display/OISSWA/Third-party+JavaScript+libraries+not+scanned+by+Fortify), why the scan defaults to excluding third-party libraries? I found this [article](https://techbeacon.com/third-party-libraries-are-one-most-insecure-parts-application) and it seems any open source library you use, it would be in your best interest to get these issues fixed by poll request. I noticed some of the findings I get from a Fortify scan are typically false positives, is this why now Fortify excludes third-party libraries? Is there a legitimate reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because of you as the owner of the code cannot really fix an issue in a third-party library. The only thing you can do is suppressing the issue. This can be even true in case of dependencies maintained by another team of the same company.
So I try to manage this as an opportunity to make the auditing process simpler by using these settings.